# `resolve_dtor() `Parentheses Algorithm

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, ddmathparser

I'm running into a frustrating problem with a parentheses completion algorithm. The math library I'm using, DDMathParser, only processes trigonometric functions in radians. If one wishes to use degrees, they must call `dtor(deg_value)`. The problem is that this adds an additional parenthesis that must be accounted for at the end.

For example, the math expression `sin(cos(sin(x)))` would translate to `sin(dtor(cos(dtor(sin(dtor(x)))` in my code. However, notice that I need two additional parentheses in order for it to be a complete math expression. Hence, the creation of `resolve_dtor()`.

Here is my attempted solution, the idea was to have `0` signify a left-paren, `1` signify a left-paren *with* `dtor(`, and `2` signify a right-paren thus completing either `0` or `1`.

```
- (NSMutableString *)resolve_dtor:(NSMutableString *)exp
{
    NSInteger mutable_length = [exp length];
    NSMutableArray *paren_complete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];     // NO/YES

    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < mutable_length; index++) {

        if ([exp characterAtIndex:index] == '(') {

            // Check if it is "dtor()"
            if (index > 5 && [[exp substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index - 4, 4)] isEqual:@"dtor"]) {
                //dtor_array_index = [self find_incomplete_paren:paren_complete];
                [paren_complete addObject:@1];
            }
            else
                [paren_complete addObject:@0];      // 0 signifies an incomplete parenthetical expression
        }
        else if ([exp characterAtIndex:index] == ')' && [paren_complete count] >= 1) {

            // Check if "dtor("
            if (![self elem_is_zero:paren_complete]) {
                // Add right-paren for "dtor("
                [paren_complete replaceObjectAtIndex:[self find_incomplete_dtor:paren_complete] withObject:@2];
                [exp insertString:@")" atIndex:index + 1];
                mutable_length++;
                index++;
            }
            else
                [paren_complete replaceObjectAtIndex:[self find_incomplete_paren:paren_complete] withObject:@2];
        }
        else if ([paren_complete count] >= 1 && [[paren_complete objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToValue:@2]) {
            // We know that everything is complete
            [paren_complete removeAllObjects];
        }
    }

    return exp;
}

- (bool)check_dtor:(NSMutableString *)exp
{
    NSMutableArray *paren_complete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];     // NO/YES

    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [exp length]; index++) {

        if ([exp characterAtIndex:index] == '(') {

            // Check if it is "dtor()"
            if (index > 5 && [[exp substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index - 4, 4)] isEqual:@"dtor"]) {
                //dtor_array_index = [self find_incomplete_paren:paren_complete];
                [paren_complete addObject:@1];
            }
            else
                [paren_complete addObject:@0];      // 0 signifies an incomplete parenthetical expression
        }
        else if ([exp characterAtIndex:index] == ')' && [paren_complete count] >= 1) {

            // Check if "dtor("
            if (![self elem_is_zero:paren_complete]) {
                // Indicate "dtor(" at index is now complete
                [paren_complete replaceObjectAtIndex:[self find_incomplete_dtor:paren_complete] withObject:@2];
            }
            else
                [paren_complete replaceObjectAtIndex:[self find_incomplete_paren:paren_complete] withObject:@2];
        }
        else if ([paren_complete count] >= 1 && [[paren_complete objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToValue:@2]) {
            // We know that everything is complete
            [paren_complete removeAllObjects];
        }
    }

    // Now step back and see if all the "dtor(" expressions are complete
    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [paren_complete count]; index++) {
        if ([[paren_complete objectAtIndex:index] isEqualToValue:@0] || [[paren_complete objectAtIndex:index] isEqualToValue:@1]) {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

It seems the algorithm works for `sin((3 + 3) + (6 - 3))` (translating to `sin(dtor((3 + 3) x (6 - 3))`) but not `sin((3 + 3) + cos(3))` (translating to `sin(dtor((3 + 3) + cos(dtor(3))`.

**Bottom Line**

This semi-solution is most likely overcomplicated (one of my common problems, it seems), so I was wondering if there might be an easier way to do this?

### Solution

Here is my solution to @j_random_hacker's pseudo code he provided:

```
- (NSMutableString *)resolve_dtor:(NSString *)exp
{
    uint depth = 0;
    NSMutableArray *stack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSRegularExpression *regex_trig = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(sin|cos|tan|csc|sec|cot)" options:0 error:0];
    NSRegularExpression *regex_trig2nd = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(asin|acos|atan|acsc|asec|acot)" options:0 error:0];
    // need another regex for checking asin, etc. (because of differing index size)
    NSMutableString *exp_copy = [NSMutableString stringWithString:exp];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [exp_copy length]; i++) {
        // Check for it!
        if ([exp_copy characterAtIndex:i] == '(') {

            if (i >= 4) {
                // check if i - 4
                if ([regex_trig2nd numberOfMatchesInString:exp_copy options:0 range:NSMakeRange(i - 4, 4)] == 1) {
                    [stack addObject:@(depth)];
                    [exp_copy insertString:@"dtor(" atIndex:i + 1];
                    depth++;
                }
            }
            else if (i >= 3) {
                // check if i - 3
                if ([regex_trig numberOfMatchesInString:exp_copy options:0 range:NSMakeRange(i - 3, 3)] == 1) {
                    [stack addObject:@(depth)];
                    [exp_copy insertString:@"dtor(" atIndex:i + 1];
                    depth++;
                }
            }

        }
        else if ([exp_copy characterAtIndex:i] == ')') {
            depth--;
            if ([stack count] > 0 && [[stack objectAtIndex:[stack count] - 1]  isEqual: @(depth)]) {
                [stack removeObjectAtIndex:[stack count] - 1];
                [exp_copy insertString:@")" atIndex:i + 1];
            }
        }
    }

    return exp_copy;
}
```

It works! Let me know if there are any minor corrections that would be good to add or if there is a more efficient approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried reading your code, but I would use a simple approach in which we scan forward through the input string writing out a second string as we go while maintaining a variable called `depth` that records the current nesting level of parentheses, as well as a stack that remembers the nesting levels that need an extra `)` because we added a `dtor(` when we entered them:

- Set `depth` to 0.
- For each character `c` in the input string:

  - Write it to the output.
  - Is `c` a `(`?  If so:

    - Was the preceding token `sin`, `cos` etc.?  If so, push the current value of `depth` on a stack, and write out `dtor(`.
    - Increment `depth`.
  - Is `c` a `)`?  If so:

    - Decrement `depth`.
    - Is the top of the stack equal to `depth`?  If so, pop it and write out `)`.

Comment: This sounds like a good approach, I will attempt it and get back.

Answer (score 1):

DDMathParser natively supports using degrees for trigonometric functions and will insert the relevant `dtor` functions for you. It'll even automatically insert it by doing:

```
@"sin(42°)"
```

You can do this by setting the `angleMeasurementMode` on the relevant `DDMathEvaluator` object.

Comment: @Biff you're welcome! Using the ° operator lets you keep the `angleMeasurementMode` in Radians if you want, and just use degrees in the spots where it makes sense. Or, flipping the mode means you can just do `sin(45)` and get the right answer.